# Как вывести строку по id php ?id=1

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Добрый день я только начал изучение языка php и mysql

и у меня появился вопрос как вывести определенную строку скажем с id 1 или 2

пример site.com/?id=1 или site.com/?id=2

вот мой код который я получил за 50 минут эволюции

```html
<?php
include 'config.php'; // получили соединение с бд

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `product`") ;



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>Идентификатор</td>
    <td>Наименование</td>
    <td>Цена</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
    while($prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $prod['id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $prod['name']; ?></td><td><?php echo $prod['price']; ?> </td></tr>
        <?php
    }
  ?>
</table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE id='$id'") ;
```

Comment: Я вас очень, очень прошу, не писать ответов на вопросы по темам в которых вы не понимаете. Не нужно заниматься вредительством, даже из лучших побуждений.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну так дайте правильный ответ, если знаете. Я вас очень, очень прошу, не флудить в своём стиле. И в чём я не прав?

Comment: Господи, ДА ВО ВСЁМ! Начиная с того что $_GET['id'] может вообще не быть, и заканчивать sql инъекциями. **Вы вообще ничего** не знаете про РНР. Это не попытка вас оскорбить, а констатация факта. Причем в силу [известного эффекта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) вы не в состоянии это понять самостоятельно, вам-то разумеется кажется что вы уже эксперт. Поэтому надо прислушиваться к тому что вам говорят другие.

Comment: Дебилы не могут понять, что они дебилы, потому что они дебилы? )))) И это говорит мне известный мега-флудер, у которого я не видел НИ ОДНОГО ответа, относящегося к делу. Пафоса дохрена, а что толку? Человек ясно написал, что только начал изучение PHP, и ему нужно понять смысл работы. А инъекции и отсутствие параметра к вопросу не относится